# My Javascript won't call its child script

Tags: javascript, web-testing

The relevant side of the code has been included. The problems is my script wont call its child script.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 if (document.documentElement.clientwidth < 640) {   
     document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript"        src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/external/flash/metalradio.mcast.com:44536:1:000000:f     fffff:ffffff:::1"> <\/scr' + 'ipt>';
 };
 </script>

 <body>
     <div id = "other">
         <!--Nothing happens using above script-->
     </div>

     <div id ="another">
         <!--displays flash player -->
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/external/flash/metalradio.mcast.com:44536:1:000000:f     fffff:ffffff:::1"></script>
     </div>
 <body>
```

Am I missing some escape character or something? I have everything.

Comment: why is your ending tag split like this? <\/`scr' + 'ipt>'`

Comment: also document.documentElement.clientwidth is returning a string so it would be like '620px' which means you can't compare it to 640. you need to parse it: `var x = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientwidth, 10) if(x < 640)...` pretty sure your not getting into your if statement.

Answer (score -1):

im not sure that is the proper way to add elements to the DOM in javascript, you will have to use something like createElement

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_createelement.asp

in jQuery it is a bit more simple since .html() will make the element for you

edit:

here is pretty much what you are trying to do i believe

http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm

Comment: innerhtml is by far the easiest way to add to the dom. createelement is the standard yes but most don't use it as it is clunky.

Comment: @Ryan: Actually `innerhtml` and `createelement` don't even exist in any implementation of Javascript I know. `innerHTML` and `createElement` do though. And who cares which one you use as long as it works. Plus, `createElement` is really useful if you use tools to help write out your nodes. `innerHTML` *can* be clunky.

Comment: @trinithis `innerHTML` is not a standard its from internet explorer but was used so much all the other browser adopted it, if you want to get nit picky. And yes it *can* be clunky the whole dom can...